# AWS - Download all versions of S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file in a S3 bucket with 60 versions. I need to download all versions but using the console I would have to download one by one.

Is there a command to download all the versions?
Or a way to make a lambda function read all the versions and download them as different files to another S3 bucket?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use [`list-object-versions`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html) to list all object versions, then use [`cp`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) to download each version in turn.  The same actions are possible in Lambda with the AWS SDK for the language of your choice.

Comment: Just to confirm I would do something like:
`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket buckename --prefix object cp nameOfAnotherBucket` ?

Comment: No.  You would use `list-object-versions`, and have some tool or script parse the output and call `cp` multiple times with each version.

Comment: What programming environment do you normally use?

Comment: I use vscode ou jupyter notebooks